# Accepting data from manual input or piped from textfile in the same program

Tags: python

I've written a program that start with asking a few questions. It should have this functionality, but since it is sometimes tedious to allways enter the answers manually, Id also like to have the option of using a textfile for an argument when I start the program. The important thing is that I wan't to have both options.

Imagine that I have written the program knight.py:

```
def main():
   answer1 = raw_input("What is your name? ")
   answer2 = raw_input("What is your quest? ")
   answer3 = raw_input("What is your favourite colour? ")

   print answer1
   print answer2
   print answer3
```

Now I would like to run it either by simply writing

```
> knight.py
```

on the command line, or by writing

```
> knight.py answers.txt
```

Where answers.txt looks like this:

```
Lancelot
To seek the holy grail
Blue
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is give your python script the ability to read command line arguments.

Take a look here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html

Once you have done this, you can read in your file using basic python file readers like here:

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files